# jQuery .on function not working after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, click, load

My jQuery .click functions are not working on content that is loaded with ajax. I changed my .click to .on ("click") functions because I read that event delegation would fix the problem. Here is my ajax call:

```
    $(".piece:nth-child(1)").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "terra.html",
            datatype: "html",
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $("body").fadeOut(function() {
                    $(this).html(data).slideDown(500);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

And this is the function that is not working after the ajax call:

```
$(document).on('click', ".pin", function() {
    $(this).css("z-index", "99");
    $(".dropdown-container").animate({"top": "0px"}, 500, "ease");
    $(".terra-arrow-dropdown").show();
    $(".interact .terra-arrow").fadeOut(300);
    $(".interact .screen").addClass("screen-opacity");
});
```

Comment: Is the element with the .pin class on the page when it is loaded?

Comment: @user2182349 it is on the page being loaded with Ajax, which is titled terra.html. It is not on the index.html page

Comment: @AustinBranham What are contents of `terra.html` ?

Comment: @guest271314 Its part of a web design portfolio. The entire document includes a number of things, interactive divs, images etc

Comment: @guest271314 what would be the best way of sending you the contents of terra.html?

Comment: @AustinBranham Is entire document returned ? Or does `terra.html` contain only element fragments ? Does returned `html` include `<!doctype>` declration ? , `<html>` element ? Does returned `html` contain `.pin` , `.piece` elements ?

Comment: @guest271314 yes it includes all of that. Yes the returned html includes those elements

Comment: @guest271314 this is the error web inspector gives me when I click on the div that is not working: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'n.easing[this.easing](a,this.options.duration*a,0,1,this.options.duration)')

Comment: It points to this line as the error in my js file: 

$(".dropdown-container").animate({"top": "0px"}, 500, "ease");

Comment: Try changing `"ease"` to `"swing"` or `"linear"` if jQuery UI is not loaded . `"ease"` is not a defined jQuery easing function

Comment: @guest271314 I've defined "ease" in my js file though using the jQuery plugin, like so: ease: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
            if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t + b;
            return c/2*((t-=2)*t*t + 2) + b;
        }
    });

Comment: Add your $ajax result that i test it.

Answer (score 1):

> Does returned `html` include `<!doctype>` declration ? , `<html>` element ?
>
> yes it includes all of that.

Appear `body` element is overwritten at

```
$("body").fadeOut(function() {
  $(this).html(data).slideDown(500);
});
```

Try removing `<!doctype>` declaration , `<html>` , `<body>` tags from `terra.html` .

If `<script>` tags are in `body` element , move `script` elements to `head` of original document , for `script` where

```
$(document).on('click', ".pin", function() {
```

not to be overwritten when

```
$(this).html(data)
```

called , which replaces all `html` of `body` element - including any child `script` elements

Comment: Actually, removing the easing parameters in my animate functions did the trick. Would it be proper to also go ahead and fix all of this as well?

Answer (score 0):

Check your console.log for errors. My guess is that your ajax callback function is failing because jQuery's fadeOut's first parameter is the duration and the second is the callback function. So you would need something like this.

```
$(".piece:nth-child(1)").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "terra.html",
        datatype: "html",
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $("body").fadeOut(500, function() {
                $(this).html(data).slideDown(500);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The way you are doing event delegation ( `$(document).on('click', ".pin", function() {...` ) should work.

Comment: This unfortunately did not fix it. I've included some info in the comment section above.